# Find the maximum value of four dimensional matrix along with the indices

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the entry of matrix `A`that has the maximum value. 
I have generated matrix `A`, how can I ask MATLAB to return the four indices in addition to the maximum value of the entry within matrix A

```
for i = 1:size(CB,2)
    for j=1:size(CB,2)
        for k=1:size(CB,2)
            for l=1:size(CB,2)
                A(i,j,k,l)= (abs( conj(transpose([CB(:,i); CB(:,j)]))*MATRIX* [CB(:,k); CB(:,l)])^2);
            end
        end 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
a = rand(5, 5, 5, 5);

[maxa, maxidx] = max(a(:));
[I, J, K, L] = ind2sub(size(a), maxidx);
```

Which we can test:

```
>> a(I, J, K, L) == maxa

ans =

     1
```

The way this works is that we receive a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) from the second output of the `max` command. I used the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) with `max` so our input is really one long column vector of `a`, and the output is the maximum value of the entire matrix, `maxa`, along with the location of that value in the column vector, `maxidx`. You can then use `ind2sub` with [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) to convert that linear index into subscripts for your matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Use 1-D indexing:

`[M,I] = max(A(:));`

`I` is then the index in `A` where `M` resides (i.e., `M = A(I)`)

Then you need to use the following to convert from 1D indexing to 4D indexing:

`[a,b,c,d] = ind2sub(size(A),I);`